# Can't deploy war to Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I have spring boot application and it works when i run it with spring boot,but when I build war and deploy it to tomcat,i get 404 status

I added this lines from spring docs to maven:

```
    <properties>

        <start-class>com.example.deploytest.DeploytestApplication</start-class>
    </properties>

    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And here is my main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DeploytestApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DeploytestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(DeploytestApplication.class);
    }
}
```

And simple controller:

```
@RestController
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping
    public String hello() {
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

My tomcat version is 10.0.27

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pom.xml should look similar to this:

```
<dependencies>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If missing you can also try to add the SpringBootServletInitializer interface in you main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootTomcatApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
}
```

Comment: How to disable it?

Comment: I've tried this but i still have 404 status (

Comment: Please try to add SpringBootServletInitializer interface if missing.

Comment: i have it in main class ,please check it in question

Comment: Could it be that your <dependency> is not wrapped by a <dependencies>? Please try the entry from the pom.xml i provide in the answer.

Comment: No, it's wrapped. I think something wrong with spring boot bcuse i do everything that's wrote in spring docs..

Comment: Which Spring Boot version are you using? Have you tried wirh 2.7.x?

Comment: 2.7.8 and java 17. I  also tried tomcat 9 but have the same problem

Comment: It's finally worked after i set java version 8 with tomcat 9

Comment: FYI, according to [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71258240/642706), Spring Boot 2.5.5+ should support Java 17.

Answer (score 0):

try to give an url to your GetMapping

```
@GetMapping("/")
```

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

servlet api version mismatch, try to use the same version of tomcat as embedded.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).